# Visual Studio Linker Error while linking SFML-2.1

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, sfml

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i included additional directories to C:/SFML-2.1/include and linker  to C:/SFML-2.1/lib i get the errors such as following linker errors help me

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::String(char const *,class std::locale const &)" (__imp_??0String@sf@@QAE@PBDABVlocale@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::~String(void)" (__imp_??1String@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main    c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (__imp_??0VideoMode@sf@@QAE@III@Z) referenced in function _main   c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::Window::close(void)" (__imp_?close@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::isOpen(void)const " (__imp_?isOpen@Window@sf@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function _main    c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::pollEvent(class sf::Event &)" (__imp_?pollEvent@Window@sf@@QAE_NAAVEvent@2@@Z) referenced in function _main    c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::Window::display(void)" (__imp_?display@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::Color::Color(unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (__imp_??0Color@sf@@QAE@EEEE@Z) referenced in function _main c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::RenderTarget::clear(class sf::Color const &)" (__imp_?clear@RenderTarget@sf@@QAEXABVColor@2@@Z) referenced in function _main   c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::RenderTarget::draw(class sf::Drawable const &,class sf::RenderStates const &)" (__imp_?draw@RenderTarget@sf@@QAEXABVDrawable@2@ABVRenderStates@2@@Z) referenced in function _main  c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (__imp_??0RenderWindow@sf@@QAE@VVideoMode@1@ABVString@1@IABUContextSettings@1@@Z) referenced in function _main    c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow(void)" (__imp_??1RenderWindow@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   14  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::Shape::setFillColor(class sf::Color const &)" (__imp_?setFillColor@Shape@sf@@QAEXABVColor@2@@Z) referenced in function _main   c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   15  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float,unsigned int)" (__imp_??0CircleShape@sf@@QAE@MI@Z) referenced in function _main  c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
Error   16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::CircleShape::~CircleShape(void)" (__imp_??1CircleShape@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6
```

Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class sf::Color const sf::Color::Green" (__imp_?Green@Color@sf@@2V12@B) c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6

Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class sf::RenderStates const sf::RenderStates::Default" (__imp_?Default@RenderStates@sf@@2V12@B)    c:\Users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Source.obj Win32Project6

Error   19  error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals  c:\users\pradeep j\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project6\Debug\Win32Project6.exe  Win32Project6

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please give me the solution i just a beginner to programming

Comment: _"i included additional directories"_ That's not sufficient. You probably missed to specify to [link against the sfml library itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx).

Comment: STOP SHOUTING ON ME MAN! If you ask here for such you'll best specify the whole linker command line in your question, which you didn't yet. _"Please give me the solution "_ Whining doesn't help as long you're unclear as you are.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Okay can you tell me the correct solution

Comment: Are you sure you did everything right as [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574400#12574400)? Otherwise I told you already: Edit your question to complete the details.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i would sent you the pdf i referred; i done the procedure as specified in it;so that you could find the problem

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ waiting for ur reply

Comment: _"waiting for ur reply"_ Waiting for your edit :P ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your file names of *.lib files to vs' linker.

Instruction:
1.Open your project Property pages.(Press Alt+F7 in vs).
2.Expand "Configuration Properties".
3.Expand "Linker".
4.You will find item "Input" under "Linker" and click the "Input".
5.On the right side,you will find a item "Additional Dependencies".
6.Add your lib file names here.(for example lib1.lib;lib2.lib...,separate the libraries with semicolon).